# function in setInterval() executes without delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am in the process of making a jquery application to hide an image after a specified interval of time by using setInterval(). The problem is that the hide image function executes immediately without delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(change(), 99999999);

  function change() {
    $('#slideshow img').eq(0).removeClass('show');

  }

});
```

I am testing it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wWHux/2/).

Comment: `setInterval(change(), x);` -> `setInterval(change, x);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wWHux/3/

You called the function immediately instead of passing it to `setInterval`.

`setInterval( change, 1500 )` - passes function `change` to `setInterval`

`setInterval( change(), 1500 )` - calls the function `change` and passes the result (`undefined`) to `setInterval`

Answer (score 4):

Where you have `setInterval(change(), 99999999);` you end up calling the `change()` function immediately and passing the return value of it to the `setInterval()` function. You need delay the execution of `change()` by wrapping it in a function.

```
setInterval(function() { change() }, 9999999);
```

Or you can delay it by passing `setInterval()` just the function itself without calling it.

```
setInterval(change, 9999999);
```

Either works. I personally find the first one a bit clearer about the intent than the second.

Comment: I had to pass some data to the function so this wrapper helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `setInterval(change(), 99999999);` and it should be `setInterval(change, 99999999);`. See the documentation of setInterval/setTimeout why. :)

Common mistake, happens to me all the time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `setInterval(change(), 99999999);` to `setInterval(change, 99999999);`

And 99999999 means 99999999  milliseconds as you known.