# setTimeOut not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, settimeout, setinterval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [function in setInterval() executes without delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858262/function-in-setinterval-executes-without-delay)

I am trying to use setTimeOut to calla function every `X` milliseconds, but it seems that it just freaks out and counts incredibly fast no matter what timeframe I set it to? Am I doing something wrong?

```
var Count = 0;
var GameRunning = 0;

var lblTimer = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    color:'#999',
    text:'I am Window 1',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue'},
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'auto',
    height: 25,
    top: 25
});

var btnStartGame = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   title: 'Start',
   width: 50,
   height: 25,
   top: 75
});

function RunGame () {
  Count++;
  lblTimer.text = Count;
  x = setTimeout(RunGame(), 100000);
}

function StartGame () {
  if(GameRunning==0)
  {
    GameRunning = 1;
    RunGame();
  }
    else
  {
    // Stop the game.
    GameRunning = 0;
    Count = 0;
  }
}

function GameTimerCount() {
    Titanium.API.info("inside GameTimerCount");
    Count++;
    lblTimer.text = "RUNNING: " + Count;
}

btnStartGame.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    Titanium.API.info("button clicked");
    StartGame();

    //var test = setInterval("GameTimerCount()",100);
});

// Add objects to window
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(lblTimer);
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(btnStartGame);
```

Comment: See [function in setInterval() executes without delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858262/function-in-setinterval-executes-without-delay/7858280#7858280). TLDR: remove the parentheses: `x = setTimeout(RunGame(), 100000);` => `x = setTimeout(RunGame, 100000);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your setTimeout call to this:

```
setTimeout(RunGame,1000);
```

`RunGame()` returns void so having `setTimeout(RunGame(),1000);` is actually more akin to `setTimeout(void,1000);`  which does nothing.  setTimeout works by using a function pointer to know what function to execute.

Comment: There's no `void` return value in JavaScript. Functions that don't explicitely return something return `undefined`. Note that there *is* a `void` keyword but that's an entirely different thing :)

Comment: It's a metaphorical void in case he has C experience :)