# setInterval() in my greasemonkey script ignores the time given and constantly executes

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, settimeout, setinterval, wait

I have experience with programming but I am new to greasemonkey and javascript. I am made a simple greasemonkey script that reloads a page every 10 seconds. The reload works, but the pause does not so the page reloads over and over again.

This is the code I am using:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           my script
// @namespace      http://example.com
// @include        http://*.example.com/page.html*
// ==/UserScript==



var i = setInterval(pageReload(),10000);

function pageReload() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

I've tried this with the setTimeout() function and it has the same effect as above. Ditto with throwing a wait(10000) in many different places.

I am using firefox 10.0.2 and I got greasemonkey yesterday so it's the latest version.

One oddity I did notice after a lot of lookup is that the setInterval() syntax has the function name (parameter 1) in quotes, like this:

```
var i = setInterval("pageReload()",10000);
```

This causes the script to do nothing. Without the quotes, it runs but not properly.

Pre-emptive: I have deleted and reinstalled the script.

Comment: `setInterval(pageReload(),10000);`: you are **executing** `pageReload` and passing its return value to `setInterval`. Pass the function reference instead. The reason why it does not work with quotes is that the string is evaluated in global scope and I assume `pageReload` is not global.

Comment: possible duplicate of [function in setInterval() executes without delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858262/function-in-setinterval-executes-without-delay)

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the function directly at the moment (the extra brackets at the end). Try removing them:

```
var i = setInterval(pageReload,10000);
```

Or, better yet, just use an anonymous function, since you're not going to use that function more than once:

```
var i = setInterval(function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The parens:

`setInterval(pageReload(),10000)`

*call* `pageReload()` assigning whatever it returns to `setInterval`, instead;

`setInterval(pageReload,10000)`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. It is working how I expected it to now.